# Calling javascript and C# on button/link click

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I currently have a Gridview with a itemTemplate which acts as a link which calls a javascript function:

```
 <ItemTemplate>
            <a href="javascript:;" onclick="simpleCart.add( 'name=<%# Eval("Name") %>' , 'price=<%# Eval("Price") %>' , 'quantity=1' );">Add To Cart</a>
            </ItemTemplate>
```

I need to add some functionality which I can only do in C#, so I was thinking of replacing the link with a button and when the button is clicked it calls both the C# function and the javascript function (they don't need to interact/share any data). Is this even possible?

Comment: When do you need to call the javascript function? Before or after the server side?

Comment: Doesn't really make a difference in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a LinkButton and set the OnClientClick property to execute a javascript function before going to the server. You could even cancel the server call if you return false from this function:

```
<asp:LinkButton 
    id="LinkButton1"
    text="Add To Cart"
    OnClientClick='<%# string.Format("&quot;name={0}&quot;, &quot;price={1}&quot;, &quot;quantity=1&quot;", Eval("Name"), Eval("Price")) %>'
    OnClick="LinkButton1_Click"
    runat="Server" />
```

Comment: I think that's how I have to do it, but now I'm getting the error "The server tag is not well formed." The problem is in the javascript part (onClientClick), I just copied how it was in my original post. p.s. I apologise for taking so long to reply, went away for the rest of the weekend

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OnClientClick` properyy of `LinkButton` in order to execute client script and `OnClick` event for server code

Here is code example and more detailed description http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.onclientclick.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

It sounds like you want to avoid a full-page postback, so you could call the server-side code either with an ASP.NET Callback or with a more vanilla Ajax call, perhaps using jQuery. (I'm assuming your C# code is on the server, rather than in a local Silverlight app).